# Android app working on emulator but on device

Tags: android, device

I'm running my android application on the emulator (version 4.2) and it works fine. However, when I try the application on my android device (version 2.3) it doesn't work. I get errors in the log as follows:

```
06-05 18:32:12.054: I/ActivityThread(3950): Pub com.gfone.db: com.gfone.db.DBProvider
06-05 18:32:16.804: I/ApplicationPackageManager(3950): cscCountry is not German : INS
06-05 18:33:06.515: D/dalvikvm(3950): GC_CONCURRENT freed 175K, 46% free 3087K/5639K, external 408K/517K, paused 3ms+5ms
06-05 18:33:06.554: E/SIP SRV(3950): RESET SETTINGS !!!!
06-05 18:33:54.750: I/ActivityThread(4102): Pub com.gfone.db: com.gfone.db.DBProvider
06-05 18:33:55.125: D/dalvikvm(4102): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.gfone/lib/libstlport_shared.so 0x405186b8
06-05 18:33:55.125: D/dalvikvm(4102): Added shared lib /data/data/com.gfone/lib/libstlport_shared.so 0x405186b8
06-05 18:33:55.125: D/dalvikvm(4102): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.gfone/lib/libstlport_shared.so 0x405186b8, skipping init
06-05 18:33:55.125: D/dalvikvm(4102): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.gfone/lib/libpjsipjni.so 0x405186b8
06-05 18:33:55.140: D/dalvikvm(4102): Added shared lib /data/data/com.gfone/lib/libpjsipjni.so 0x405186b8
06-05 18:33:55.593: D/dalvikvm(4102): GC_CONCURRENT freed 199K, 47% free 3033K/5639K, external 408K/517K, paused 3ms+4ms
06-05 18:33:55.890: I/ApplicationPackageManager(4102): cscCountry is not German : INS
06-05 18:33:57.929: D/dalvikvm(4102): GC_EXPLICIT freed 75K, 46% free 3080K/5639K, external 408K/517K, paused 51ms
06-05 18:34:04.976: E/libpjsip(4102): 18:34:04.983 sip_transport. !Error processing 771 bytes packet from UDP 199.33.127.83:5060 : PJSIP syntax error exception when parsing '' header on line 9 col 37:
06-05 18:34:04.976: E/libpjsip(4102): SIP/2.0 200 OK
06-05 18:34:04.976: E/libpjsip(4102): Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.8:50400;received=122.177.170.210;rport=50400;branch=z9hG4bKPjhOLshga3nSyqdFZWKFXSHPEFnMBU1LR7
06-05 18:34:04.976: E/libpjsip(4102): Max-Forwards: 70
06-05 18:34:04.976: E/libpjsip(4102): From: "777" <sip:777@vos3.gventure.net>;tag=r.BwtxIkpYiwTJ-8OcR23P2TTm7NvkT9
06-05 18:34:04.976: E/libpjsip(4102): To: "777" <sip:777@vos3.gventure.net>
06-05 18:34:04.976: E/libpjsip(4102): Call-ID: Di-8Pw7tb6xNHDCiKbKXI85kFjqEpE3Z
06-05 18:34:04.976: E/libpjsip(4102): CSeq: 4635 REGISTER
06-05 18:34:04.976: E/libpjsip(4102): Authorization: Digest username="777", realm="199.33.127.83", nonce="4b53d2aab17a6228", uri="sip:vos3.gventure.net;transport=udp;lr", response="92b076067afccce16d917cbd0ca4fcb6"
06-05 18:34:04.976: E/libpjsip(4102): Contact: <sip:777@192.168.1.8:50400:50400;ob>
06-05 18:34:04.976: E/libpjsip(4102): Contact: "777" <sip:777@192.168.1.8:50400;ob>;expires=0
06-05 18:34:04.976: E/libpjsip(4102): Expires: 60
06-05 18:34:04.976: E/libpjsip(4102): Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
06-05 18:34:04.976: E/libpjsip(4102): Content-Length: 0
06-05 18:34:04.976: E/libpjsip(4102): Server: VOS2009 V2.1.1.5
06-05 18:34:04.976: E/libpjsip(4102): 
06-05 18:34:04.976: E/libpjsip(4102): -- end of packet.
06-05 18:34:05.492: E/libpjsip(4102): 18:34:05.498 sip_transport.  Error processing 771 bytes packet from UDP 199.33.127.83:5060 : PJSIP syntax error exception when parsing '' header on line 9 col 37:
06-05 18:34:05.492: E/libpjsip(4102): SIP/2.0 200 OK
06-05 18:34:05.492: E/libpjsip(4102): Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.8:50400;received=122.177.170.210;rport=50400;branch=z9hG4bKPjhOLshga3nSyqdFZWKFXSHPEFnMBU1LR7
06-05 18:34:05.492: E/libpjsip(4102): Max-Forwards: 70
06-05 18:34:05.492: E/libpjsip(4102): From: "777" <sip:777@vos3.gventure.net>;tag=r.BwtxIkpYiwTJ-8OcR23P2TTm7NvkT9
06-05 18:34:05.492: E/libpjsip(4102): To: "777" <sip:777@vos3.gventure.net>
06-05 18:34:05.492: E/libpjsip(4102): Call-ID: Di-8Pw7tb6xNHDCiKbKXI85kFjqEpE3Z
06-05 18:34:05.492: E/libpjsip(4102): CSeq: 4635 REGISTER
06-05 18:34:05.492: E/libpjsip(4102): Authorization: Digest username="777", realm="199.33.127.83", nonce="4b53d2aab17a6228", uri="sip:vos3.gventure.net;transport=udp;lr", response="92b076067afccce16d917cbd0ca4fcb6"
06-05 18:34:05.492: E/libpjsip(4102): Contact: <sip:777@192.168.1.8:50400:50400;ob>
06-05 18:34:05.492: E/libpjsip(4102): Contact: "777" <sip:777@192.168.1.8:50400;ob>;expires=0
06-05 18:34:05.492: E/libpjsip(4102): Expires: 60
06-05 18:34:05.492: E/libpjsip(4102): Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
06-05 18:34:05.492: E/libpjsip(4102): Content-Length: 0
06-05 18:34:05.492: E/libpjsip(4102): Server: VOS2009 V2.1.1.5
06-05 18:34:05.492: E/libpjsip(4102): 
06-05 18:34:05.492: E/libpjsip(4102): -- end of packet.
06-05 18:34:06.515: E/libpjsip(4102): 18:34:06.519 sip_transport.  Error processing 771 bytes packet from UDP 199.33.127.83:5060 : PJSIP syntax error exception when parsing '' header on line 9 col 37:
06-05 18:34:06.515: E/libpjsip(4102): SIP/2.0 200 OK
06-05 18:34:06.515: E/libpjsip(4102): Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.8:50400;received=122.177.170.210;rport=50400;branch=z9hG4bKPjhOLshga3nSyqdFZWKFXSHPEFnMBU1LR7
06-05 18:34:06.515: E/libpjsip(4102): Max-Forwards: 70
06-05 18:34:06.515: E/libpjsip(4102): From: "777" <sip:777@vos3.gventure.net>;tag=r.BwtxIkpYiwTJ-8OcR23P2TTm7NvkT9
06-05 18:34:06.515: E/libpjsip(4102): To: "777" <sip:777@vos3.gventure.net>
06-05 18:34:06.515: E/libpjsip(4102): Call-ID: Di-8Pw7tb6xNHDCiKbKXI85kFjqEpE3Z
06-05 18:34:06.515: E/libpjsip(4102): CSeq: 4635 REGISTER
06-05 18:34:06.515: E/libpjsip(4102): Authorization: Digest username="777", realm="199.33.127.83", nonce="4b53d2aab17a6228", uri="sip:vos3.gventure.net;transport=udp;lr", response="92b076067afccce16d917cbd0ca4fcb6"
06-05 18:34:06.515: E/libpjsip(4102): Contact: <sip:777@192.168.1.8:50400:50400;ob>
06-05 18:34:06.515: E/libpjsip(4102): Contact: "777" <sip:777@192.168.1.8:50400;ob>;expires=0
06-05 18:34:06.515: E/libpjsip(4102): Expires: 60
06-05 18:34:06.515: E/libpjsip(4102): Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
06-05 18:34:06.515: E/libpjsip(4102): Content-Length: 0
06-05 18:34:06.515: E/libpjsip(4102): Server: VOS2009 V2.1.1.5
06-05 18:34:06.515: E/libpjsip(4102): 
06-05 18:34:06.515: E/libpjsip(4102): -- end of packet.
06-05 18:34:08.460: E/libpjsip(4102): 18:34:08.465 sip_transport.  Error processing 771 bytes packet from UDP 199.33.127.83:5060 : PJSIP syntax error exception when parsing '' header on line 9 col 37:
06-05 18:34:08.460: E/libpjsip(4102): SIP/2.0 200 OK
06-05 18:34:08.460: E/libpjsip(4102): Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.8:50400;received=122.177.170.210;rport=50400;branch=z9hG4bKPjhOLshga3nSyqdFZWKFXSHPEFnMBU1LR7
06-05 18:34:08.460: E/libpjsip(4102): Max-Forwards: 70
06-05 18:34:08.460: E/libpjsip(4102): From: "777" <sip:777@vos3.gventure.net>;tag=r.BwtxIkpYiwTJ-8OcR23P2TTm7NvkT9
06-05 18:34:08.460: E/libpjsip(4102): To: "777" <sip:777@vos3.gventure.net>
06-05 18:34:08.460: E/libpjsip(4102): Call-ID: Di-8Pw7tb6xNHDCiKbKXI85kFjqEpE3Z
06-05 18:34:08.460: E/libpjsip(4102): CSeq: 4635 REGISTER
06-05 18:34:08.460: E/libpjsip(4102): Authorization: Digest username="777", realm="199.33.127.83", nonce="4b53d2aab17a6228", uri="sip:vos3.gventure.net;transport=udp;lr", response="92b076067afccce16d917cbd0ca4fcb6"
06-05 18:34:08.460: E/libpjsip(4102): Contact: <sip:777@192.168.1.8:50400:50400;ob>
06-05 18:34:08.460: E/libpjsip(4102): Contact: "777" <sip:777@192.168.1.8:50400;ob>;expires=0
06-05 18:34:08.460: E/libpjsip(4102): Expires: 60
06-05 18:34:08.460: E/libpjsip(4102): Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
06-05 18:34:08.460: E/libpjsip(4102): Content-Length: 0
06-05 18:34:08.460: E/libpjsip(4102): Server: VOS2009 V2.1.1.5
06-05 18:34:08.460: E/libpjsip(4102): 
06-05 18:34:08.460: E/libpjsip(4102): -- end of packet.
06-05 18:34:12.554: E/libpjsip(4102): 18:34:12.562 sip_transport.  Error processing 771 bytes packet from UDP 199.33.127.83:5060 : PJSIP syntax error exception when parsing '' header on line 9 col 37:
06-05 18:34:12.554: E/libpjsip(4102): SIP/2.0 200 OK
06-05 18:34:12.554: E/libpjsip(4102): Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.8:50400;received=122.177.170.210;rport=50400;branch=z9hG4bKPjhOLshga3nSyqdFZWKFXSHPEFnMBU1LR7
06-05 18:34:12.554: E/libpjsip(4102): Max-Forwards: 70
06-05 18:34:12.554: E/libpjsip(4102): From: "777" <sip:777@vos3.gventure.net>;tag=r.BwtxIkpYiwTJ-8OcR23P2TTm7NvkT9
06-05 18:34:12.554: E/libpjsip(4102): To: "777" <sip:777@vos3.gventure.net>
06-05 18:34:12.554: E/libpjsip(4102): Call-ID: Di-8Pw7tb6xNHDCiKbKXI85kFjqEpE3Z
06-05 18:34:12.554: E/libpjsip(4102): CSeq: 4635 REGISTER
06-05 18:34:12.554: E/libpjsip(4102): Authorization: Digest username="777", realm="199.33.127.83", nonce="4b53d2aab17a6228", uri="sip:vos3.gventure.net;transport=udp;lr", response="92b076067afccce16d917cbd0ca4fcb6"
06-05 18:34:12.554: E/libpjsip(4102): Contact: <sip:777@192.168.1.8:50400:50400;ob>
06-05 18:34:12.554: E/libpjsip(4102): Contact: "777" <sip:777@192.168.1.8:50400;ob>;expires=0
06-05 18:34:12.554: E/libpjsip(4102): Expires: 60
06-05 18:34:12.554: E/libpjsip(4102): Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
06-05 18:34:12.554: E/libpjsip(4102): Content-Length: 0
06-05 18:34:12.554: E/libpjsip(4102): Server: VOS2009 V2.1.1.5
06-05 18:34:12.554: E/libpjsip(4102): 
06-05 18:34:12.554: E/libpjsip(4102): -- end of packet.
06-05 18:34:16.593: E/libpjsip(4102): 18:34:16.601 sip_transport.  Error processing 771 bytes packet from UDP 199.33.127.83:5060 : PJSIP syntax error exception when parsing '' header on line 9 col 37:
06-05 18:34:16.593: E/libpjsip(4102): SIP/2.0 200 OK
06-05 18:34:16.593: E/libpjsip(4102): Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.8:50400;received=122.177.170.210;rport=50400;branch=z9hG4bKPjhOLshga3nSyqdFZWKFXSHPEFnMBU1LR7
06-05 18:34:16.593: E/libpjsip(4102): Max-Forwards: 70
06-05 18:34:16.593: E/libpjsip(4102): From: "777" <sip:777@vos3.gventure.net>;tag=r.BwtxIkpYiwTJ-8OcR23P2TTm7NvkT9
06-05 18:34:16.593: E/libpjsip(4102): To: "777" <sip:777@vos3.gventure.net>
06-05 18:34:16.593: E/libpjsip(4102): Call-ID: Di-8Pw7tb6xNHDCiKbKXI85kFjqEpE3Z
06-05 18:34:16.593: E/libpjsip(4102): CSeq: 4635 REGISTER
06-05 18:34:16.593: E/libpjsip(4102): Authorization: Digest username="777", realm="199.33.127.83", nonce="4b53d2aab17a6228", uri="sip:vos3.gventure.net;transport=udp;lr", response="92b076067afccce16d917cbd0ca4fcb6"
06-05 18:34:16.593: E/libpjsip(4102): Contact: <sip:777@192.168.1.8:50400:50400;ob>
06-05 18:34:16.593: E/libpjsip(4102): Contact: "777" <sip:777@192.168.1.8:50400;ob>;expires=0
06-05 18:34:16.593: E/libpjsip(4102): Expires: 60
06-05 18:34:16.593: E/libpjsip(4102): Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
06-05 18:34:16.593: E/libpjsip(4102): Content-Length: 0
06-05 18:34:16.593: E/libpjsip(4102): Server: VOS2009 V2.1.1.5
06-05 18:34:16.593: E/libpjsip(4102): 
06-05 18:34:16.593: E/libpjsip(4102): -- end of packet.
```

What in these logs give me a clue as to what is going wrong?

Comment: Check the android:minSdkVersion field in your project manifest file. If it is greater than 2.3, then it wont work on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Set the attribute as android:minSdkVersion="8" in your manifest file. This should make your application work on your device (v2.3)